# Faster CSS Background Color Fade

Tags: html, css, colors, background, fade

I have successfully added a color fading background to my html form, but I would like it to be more drastic (meaning that I would like it to go from the lighter color to the darker color sooner on the page). Could someone provide an example of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Show what you currently have

Comment: Could you add some code- eg at codepen.io or jsfiddle.net? This means that those who can help can see your problem more easily.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery fading feature

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

You can set the fading speed

Comment: But he can't set start and end color. It means - he needs additional plugin for color transition(s)...

Comment: it is still possible, for example is by overlaying 2 divs with different colors, then fades the top one